# Magento loose table details in Google sitemap

Tags: magento, sitemap

I have problems with google sitemap.

as you can see in [here](http://s7.postimg.org/otmb4ddwr/mysitemap.jpg), I lost the detail table!...if i click add sitemap i get white page!

How can do to restore?

thank you 
regards

Answer (score 0):

You may have issue in "/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sitemap/Grid.php". So check the file. Here is a code of Grid.php

```
class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sitemap_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->setId('sitemapGrid');
    $this->setDefaultSort('sitemap_id');

}

protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getModel('sitemap/sitemap')->getCollection();
    /* @var $collection Mage_Sitemap_Model_Mysql4_Sitemap_Collection */
    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}

protected function _prepareColumns()
{
    $this->addColumn('sitemap_id', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('sitemap')->__('ID'),
        'width'     => '50px',
        'index'     => 'sitemap_id'
    ));

    $this->addColumn('sitemap_filename', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('sitemap')->__('Filename'),
        'index'     => 'sitemap_filename'
    ));

    $this->addColumn('sitemap_path', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('sitemap')->__('Path'),
        'index'     => 'sitemap_path'
    ));

    $this->addColumn('link', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('sitemap')->__('Link for Google'),
        'index'     => 'concat(sitemap_path, sitemap_filename)',
        'renderer'  => 'adminhtml/sitemap_grid_renderer_link',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('sitemap_time', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('sitemap')->__('Last Time Generated'),
        'width'     => '150px',
        'index'     => 'sitemap_time',
        'type'      => 'datetime',
    ));


    if (!Mage::app()->isSingleStoreMode()) {
        $this->addColumn('store_id', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('sitemap')->__('Store View'),
            'index'     => 'store_id',
            'type'      => 'store',
        ));
    }

    $this->addColumn('action', array(
        'header'   => Mage::helper('sitemap')->__('Action'),
        'filter'   => false,
        'sortable' => false,
        'width'    => '100',
        'renderer' => 'adminhtml/sitemap_grid_renderer_action'
    ));

    return parent::_prepareColumns();
}

/**
 * Row click url
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getRowUrl($row)
{
    return $this->getUrl('*/*/edit', array('sitemap_id' => $row->getId()));
}
```

}